# Enumeration type in c#

Tags: c#, memory-management, enums, reference, value-type

When we create variable of enumeration type and assign it an enumeration value

```
enum Members{HighlyQualified, Qualified, Ordinary}
class
{
static void Main()
{
 Members developers = Members.HighlyQualified;
 Console.WriteLine(developers);//write out HighlyQualified
}
}
```

Since enum is value type so the value of developers is stored on stack which is returned by Members.HighlyQualified.Here we are clear that the value of developers is string which reference to the memory location of characters.

Now,

1.If we cast Members.HighlyQualifed to an int then the value returned is 0.
How it happens?

2.What value is really stored on stack for an enumeration type ?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc138362.aspx)?  It's all explained in there.

Comment: You should consider Enum values as numbers with names.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Here we are clear that the value of developers is string which reference to the memory location of characters.

No, it's not. The value of `developers` is of type `Members`. It's converted to a string by the `Console.WriteLine` method. You'll be calling the `Console.WriteLine(object)` overload, which boxes the value - and then `Console.WriteLine` will call `ToString` on that boxed value, giving the appropriate enum value name.

> If we cast Members.HighlyQualifed to an int then the value returned is 0. How it happens?

`HighlyQualified` is the first member declared in `Members`, and you haven't assigned any specific value. By default, the C# compiler assigns a value of 0 to the first declared value, then increments by 1 each time. If you cast `Members.Qualified` to `int`, you'd get 1.

> What value is really stored on stack for an enumeration type ?

The value, which is *effectively* just a number. (In this case, an `int` because that's the default underlying type. But the stack slot has the right type - the enum type.

Answer (score 3):

[The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc138362.aspx) explains the underlying type:

> By default the underlying type of each element in the enum is int.

and how the values are generated when not explicitly specified:

> When you do not specify values for the elements in the enumerator list, the values are automatically incremented by 1.

So, in your case, the declaration is equivalent to:

```
enum Members : int
{
    HighlyQualified = 0, 
    Qualified = 1, 
    Ordinary = 2
}
```

What's on the stack is the `enum` type itself (`Members` in this case), and when you call `Console.WriteLine` it will call `ToString` on that, for which, [per the docs for that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/16c1xs4z.aspx), returns:

> a string containing the name of the constant